# How to make @Html.EditorFor readonly depending on Drop List

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to make @Html.EditorFor read only until a certain drop down selection is made. So my drop down looks like this:

```
List<SelectListItem> listDepartments = new List<SelectListItem>();
listDepartments.Add(new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Text = "Sales",
                         Value = "Sales"
                     });
listDepartments.Add(new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Text = "Staff",
                         Value = "Staff",
                         Selected = true
                     });
```

and I want to make the  @Html.EditorFor read only unless the dropdown list is Staff. Is that hard to do?

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add `readonly` to the Description attribute using javascript when there is a change in Department value, ie when dropdown value equals Staff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like below with a ternary operator `?` ?

```
@{
    var isReadonly = Model.Description == "Staff"
}

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, (isReadonly 
                              ? new {  @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } 
                              : new { @class = "form-control" } 
                              ))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I prefer to do my `selects` without a helper as I find them a bit clumsy so something like...

```
@{
    var isReadonly = Model.Description == "Staff"
}

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <select name="Description" class="form-control @(isReadonly ? "readonly" : "")">
          <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please select...</option>
          @foreach (var option in Model.listDepartments)
          {
              <option value="@option.Value" @(option.Value == Model.Description ? "selected='selected'" : "")>@option.Text</option>
          }
      </select>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: htmlAttributes = (isReadonly ?

Comment: haha good spot, that's what I get for copy/pasting the question! @EbertB

Comment: I might just be having one of those days. I still get errors on this code?

Comment: This server side code will activate/deactivate the text input on initial load, but will not toggle the readonly each time the value of the dropdown changes. This must be handled on client side.

Comment: I've misread his question - I thought he wanted a select in place of the editor and if it was of value staff to be readonly. Yeah in that case go with jquery like @GeorgPatscheider has shown

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Javascript to react to client browser events like a change of the entry selected in the dropdown. The following code uses jQuery to achieve this.

1) You will need a handle on the dropdown so you can listen to its `change` event. Here I use the `@Html.IdFor()` helper to get the Ids of the input elements that were generated by`@Html.DropDownListFor()`/ `@Html.EditorFor()`. Then I create jQuery selectors based on these Ids.

2) Register an JS event handler for the `change` event of the dropdown.

3) Toggle the `readonly` attribute of the text input depending on the value selected in the dropdown.

In your cshtml page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

   // 1) get selectors
   var dropDownSelector = $('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.listDepartments)');
   var textBoxSelector = $('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Description)');

   // 2) listen to change event
   dropDownSelector.on('change', function() {

       // 3) toggle readonly attribute
       var selectedValue = dropDownSelector.val();
       if (selectedValue === 'Staff') {
           textBoxSelector.removeAttr('readonly');
       }
       else {
           textBoxSelector.attr('readonly', 'readonly');
           // maybe you also want to clear the text input?
           // textBoxSelector.val('');
       }
   });
});
</script>
```